# How to get a result

Tags: python-3.7

x = str(input())
while "a" in x:
  x.replace("a", "", 1)

print(x)
when I run this code I expect it to give me the string x without any "a"s in it, but the problem is that it doesn't give me anything. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you turn your code into code snippets in a post, to make it more readable.

Here is my implementation:

```
x = str(input())
x = x.replace('a','')
```